# Automatically Log in User

Tags: plugin-development, users, cookies

In my Controller I created a script to add a user to the database, is there a way I can automatically:

1) Log them in and 
2) Set a permanent session cookie or similar?

I basically don't want the user to have to ever log in and we will be creating the accounts for them.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for a combination of:

[craft()->userSession->login()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/craft-usersessionservice.html#method-login)

or

[craft()->userSession->loginByUserId()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/craft-usersessionservice.html#method-loginbyuserid)

along with setting the [userSessionDuration](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/config-settings.html#usersessionduration) config setting to a really high value.

Comment: Have these linked resources moved to a new URL?

Comment: @buck1112 yup... updated!